# Is there any statistical test for only std deviation?

Tags: inference

I have a data-set whose mean value if 1 and std deviation 0, it means there is no significance.
Far from mean value or std deviation can be significant.

When I calculate z score using  $Z = \frac{\mu - 1}{ \sigma}$
I do not get much significance. This suggest mean values are not significant.

But how to test for std deviation significance. How to check that std dev far from 0 is significant?

For example, I have 6 data points (red dots) and each of them if has a mean value 1 and std deviation 0 that means no significant.

Each dot is coming from different data size array. For example

```
dot 1 came from array length of 50; 
dot 2 came from array length of 30; 
dot 3 came from array length of 10;
... 
and so on
```

It seems like std. deviation is significantly different but how to test it.

[image]

Comment: A dataset with mean 1 and std 0 will just be a dataset of ones. Did you mean a mean of 0 and std of 1?

Comment: I have added one figure. Each dot I expect to mean 1 and std dev 0 for non significant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the standard deviation is zero, then any variability in the observations means, with absolute certainty, that the population does not have a standard deviation of zero.

Standard deviation of zero means no variability: the population distribution had all density on a single value.

A proof strategy in mathematics (logic, really) is that if statement A implies statement B and statement B is false, then we conclude that A must be false, too. In this case, zero standard deviation implies a single value, which is not the case. Thus, the standard deviation of the population cannot be zero.

Comment: But I do think you’ve made a mistake in your original post.

Comment: You might mean a hypothesis test for a population variance, though my post still applies when you are testing for zero variability. https://youtube.com/watch?v=PweabcpqzYI